# what values of $j$ makes this congruence solvable?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

For what values of $j$ is this congruence solvable?

$$0 \equiv xp^{a+s-b}j + yp^t\pmod{p^b} $$ where $p$ is an odd prime and $x,y$ are not divisible by $p.$ and $s,a$ are any integers.

Since the given congruence above is equivalent to $xp^{a+s−b}j + yp^t = k p^b $ for some $k$; and then I have to divide both sides by $p^m$ where $m= \operatorname{min} \{a+s−b,t,b\}$, then how can I know the values of $j$ that makes this congruence solvable (what stuck me is that the value of $m$ is not clearly specified)? could you please help me in answering this question?

**EDIT:**
I assumed that $a \geq b.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you do not know which of the quantities is minimal you can split the problem up into different cases. I presume we can assume that $a+s-b\ge 0$.

**If $m=b$**

Then the equation is satisfied for all $j$.

**If $m\ne b, a+s-b=m$**

Then $xj + yp^{t-m} = k p^{b-m}$ and the equation can be solved if and only if $j$ is a multiple of $p^n$, where $n$ is the minimum of $t-m$ and $b-m$.

**If $m\ne b, a+s-b\ne m$**

Then $xjp^{a+s-b-m} + y = k p^{b-m}$ and since $p$ is not a factor of $y$ there are no solutions.

Comment: How do you know that in the first case the equation is satisfied for all $j$?

Comment: Irrespective of the value of $j$ both terms are divisible by $p^m$ and so the congruence is automatically satisfied.

Comment: because in the first case we will get $xp^{a+s-2b}j + yp^{t-b} = k$

Comment: Yes and k can be anything. But it's probably simpler just to look at the original equation.

Comment: Ok I got your point :)

Comment: Does the assumption that $p$ be odd really required in our case? I feel like that your answer is also correct even if $p=2$ ..... am I correct?

Comment: Yes, I haven't assumed it to be odd.

Comment: Here is my second question(similar to this one) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3988115/what-values-of-j-makes-the-congruence-solvable-when-a-leq-b  just in case you would love to answer it

Comment: Thanks - I'll have a look tomorrow.