# What values of $j$ makes the congruence solvable when $a \leq b$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, solution-verification

What values of $j$ makes the congruence solvable when $a \leq b.$?

$$0 \equiv xp^{s}j + yp^t\pmod{p^a} $$ where $x,y$ are not divisible by $p.$ and $s,a$ are any integers and $a \leq b.$

Since the given congruence above is equivalent to $xp^{a+s−b}j + yp^t = u p^b $ for some $u$; and then I have to divide both sides by $p^m$ where $m= \operatorname{min} \{s,t,a\}$, then my answer for the question what values of $j$ that makes this congruence solvable is as follows:

**If $m=a$**

Then the equation is satisfied for all $j$.

**If $m\ne a, t = m$**

Then $x p ^{s-t}j + y = u p^{a-t}$ and since $p$ is not a factor of $y$ then there are no solutions.

**If $m\ne a, t \ne m$**

Then $xj + yp^{t-s} = u p^{a-s}$ and since $p$ is not a factor of $x$ there are no solutions.

**Is my solution correct?**

I have followed exactly the same procedure given to me in the solution here:

[what values of $j$ makes this congruence solvable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3982186/what-values-of-j-makes-this-congruence-solvable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have the right idea and there are lots of correct deductions, but there are errors:-

The equation on line 4 should be $$xp^sj + yp^t = u p^a.$$

The $m=a$ case is handled correctly.

In the second case, there can be solutions when $s=t$.

In the final case, your equation $xj + yp^{t-s} = u p^{a-s}$ is correct but there may be solutions when $j$ is divisible by $p$. For example, when $a=t$ and $j=Jp^{a-s}$, the equation becomes $xJ+y=u$ and so there are infinitely many solutions for $x$ and $y$.

Let's deal with one such case which you didn't consider:-

**If $m=s=t$, $m\ne a$**

Then $$xj + y = u p^{a-m}.$$

For any $j$ not divisible by $p$ we can therefore choose $y=up^{a-m}-xj$.

Comment: Why , in the second case , there can be solutions when $s=t$? could you clarify please?

Comment: I think the answer of my previous comment is the case $m=s=t, m\neq a $ you are considering at the end of your solution ..... am I correct?

Comment: Why in the final case there may be solutions when $j$ is divisible by $p,$ could you please explain that in details?

Comment: Yes to the second of the above queries. For the final case, I have added the explanation into the answer. I hope that helps.

Comment: Here is another question (more general to my previous 2 questions) just in case you want to answer it. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3988796/for-what-values-of-l-and-j-simultaneously-is-the-following-congruence-solv

Comment: For the second case, if $j$ is divisible by $p$ there will be no solution ..... correct?

Comment: Yes that's right because $y$ would have to be divisible by $p$ in that case.