# For what values of $l$ and $j$ (simultaneously) is the following congruence solvable?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Here is the congruence I want to know for what values of $l$ and $j$ (simultaneously) is it solvable?

$$ l (xp^s)^2 \equiv xp^{s}j p^{a-b} + yp^t\pmod{p^b} $$ where $x,y$ are not divisible by $p.$ and $s,a, b$ are any integers and $a \geq b.$

We have delt here [what values of $j$ makes this congruence solvable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3982186/what-values-of-j-makes-this-congruence-solvable/3982209?noredirect=1#comment8229835_3982209) with the case when $l=0,$ but I need now to know for what values of $l$ and $j$ (simultaneously) is it solvable?

Could anyone help me in studying this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A way forward**

A mechanical way of proceeding would be to analyse separately all the different possibilities such as the following one.
$$2s= s+a-b>t= b.$$

Fortunately you can group large numbers of these possibilities together. I will first do this below for all  possibilities that have $b$ as the right-hand number.

**If $b$ is the least of the four numbers**

Then $p^b$ divides all the terms and so the equations are satisfied for **all** pairs $(l,j)$.

Let's now look at a more difficult case.

**If $t\ge b>2s=s+a-b$**

Then the equation simplifies to
$$lx^2 \equiv xj \pmod{p^{b-2s}}.$$

So the equation is solvable if and only if either $l \equiv j \equiv 0\pmod{p^{b-2s}}$ or $l$ and $j$ are divisible by the same power (possibly zero) of $p$.

Apart from applying some ingenuity in lumping cases together there is little you can do to avoid some hard work which has to be carried out very carefully.

Answer (score 0):

A slicker way of tackling this problem is to apply the following general result about the solution of equations of this type. This equation is symmetrical which allows a much easier case-by-case analysis.

*Theorem 1*

Let $M=\min\{A,B,C,D\}$. Then the equation
$$Xp^A+Yp^B+Zp^C \equiv 0\pmod {p^D}$$

can be solved with $XYZ \not\equiv 0\pmod p$ if and only if either

$\bullet \hspace{1cm}M=D$

$\bullet \hspace{1cm}M$ is equal to precisely two of $\{A,B,C\}$

$\bullet \hspace{1cm}M$ is equal to all three of $\{A,B,C\}$ and $p\ne 2$.

*Proof*

CASE 1. If $M=D$

Then each of $Xp^A,Yp^B$ and $Zp^C$ is divisible by ${p^D}$ whatever the values of $X,Y$ or $Z$.

CASE 2. If $M=A=B,M<C$

The equation is solved by, for example, $Y=Z=1,X=-1-p^{C-M}$. By symmetry, we have similar solutions when $M=A=C$ and $M=B=C.$

CASE 3. If $M=A=B=C,M<D$

If $p\ne 2$ then the equation is solved by, for example, $Y=Z=1,X=p^{D-M}-2$. However, if $p=2$ then $X+Y+Z$ has to be even and so at least one of $X,Y,Z$ is even. This contradicts the fact that $p=2$ cannot divide $XYZ$.

CASE 4. If $B,C$ and $D$ are all greater than $M=A$

Dividing the equation through by $p^M$ gives
$$X+Yp^{B-M}+Zp^{C-M} \equiv 0\pmod {p^{D-M}}$$ and then we have the contradiction that $p$ divides $X$.

By symmetry, we have similar contradictions when $M=B$ and $M=C.$

**The transformation**

Let $l=Lp^U$ and $j=Jp^V$ where $LJ \not\equiv 0\pmod p$. Then let $$A=a-b+s+V,B=t,C=2s+U,D=b.$$

*Theorem 2*

For non-negative integers $a\ge b,s$ and $t$, the equation
$$l (xp^s)^2 \equiv xp^{s}j p^{a-b} + yp^t\pmod{p^b}$$
can be solved with $xy \not\equiv 0\pmod p$ if and only if the equation
$$Xp^A+Yp^B+Zp^C \equiv 0\pmod {p^D}$$
can be solved with $XYZ \not\equiv 0\pmod p$.

*Proof*

If the $x,y$ equation can be solved then simply take $$X=xJ,Y=y,Z=-Lx^2.$$

Conversely, suppose we have a solution of the $X,Y,Z$ equation. Since $X$ and $L$ are coprime to $p$ we can solve
$$x \equiv -\frac {JZ}{LX}\pmod {p^D},y \equiv -\frac {J^2YZ}{LX^2}\pmod {p^D}.$$
Then $$  xp^{s}j p^{a-b} + yp^t-l(xp^s)^2=xJp^A+yp^B-Lx^2p^C$$
and this is
$$ -\frac {J^2Z}{LX^2}(Xp^A+Yp^B+Zp^C )\equiv 0\pmod {p^D}.$$

**Conclusion**

We can now see that the original equation can be solved if and only if the quantities $$A=a-b+s+V,B=t,C=2s+U,D=b$$ satisfy the conditions of Theorem 1. Let $v_p(n)$ represent the highest power of $p$ which divides the number $n$. You will notice that the precise values of $j$ and $l$ do not affect the existence of solutions; all that matters is $v_p(j)$ and $v_p(l)$ .

CASE 1. $t\ge b$,  $v_p(l)\ge b-2s$ and  $v_p(j)\ge 2b-a-s$.

CASE 2. There are three possibilities.

$v_p(l)> t-2s$ and  $v_p(j)=b-a-s+t$.

$v_p(l)< t-2s$ and  $v_p(j)=b-a+s+v_p(l)$.

$v_p(l)= t-2s$ and  $v_p(j)>b-a+t-s$.

CASE 3. If $p\ne 2$ then $t< b$,  $v_p(l)= t-2s$ and  $v_p(j)= b-a+t-s$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118965/discussion-on-answer-by-s-dolan-for-what-values-of-l-and-j-simultaneously).

Comment: In the third case of theorem 1, should not $X = p^D - 2$ as $p^D $ does not divide p?

Comment: p^D|p  iff  $D=1.$ am I correct in what I said in those 2 comments?

Comment: Yes you're right. (It actually needs $X=p^{D-M}-2$. I've altered the Answer.

Comment: I have messaged you in the chat, could you please check that?

Comment: By the substitution you gessed, we want $p^D| p^{D-M}$, which is not correct. Am I correct?

Comment: Sorry - I've now replied in chat - my computer doesn't seem to alert me to messages in chat.

Comment: Why did not you involve case 4 of the proof of theorem 1 in its statement?

Comment: Because you wanted values of l and j for which the equation could be solved and Case 4 deals with a case where it *cannot *be solved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119112/discussion-between-confusion-and-s-dolan).

Comment: Here is the question I asked when $a \leq b$ in case you want to take a look at it https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4007124/for-what-values-of-l-and-j-simultaneously-is-the-following-congruence-solv