# How are $x \equiv -\frac {JZ}{LX}\pmod {p^D},y \equiv -\frac {J^2YZ}{LX^2}\pmod {p^D}$ calculated?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, euclidean-algorithm

In this question

[For what values of $l$ and $j$ (simultaneously) is the following congruence solvable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3988796/for-what-values-of-l-and-j-simultaneously-is-the-following-congruence-solv/3991102#3991102)

I do not understand how are $$x \equiv -\frac {JZ}{LX}\pmod {p^D},y \equiv -\frac {J^2YZ}{LX^2}\pmod {p^D}$$ calculated?

Also, I do not understand how is  $$  xp^{s}j p^{a-b} + yp^t-l(xp^s)^2=xJp^A+yp^B-Lx^2p^C$$
this
$$ -\frac {J^2Z}{LX^2}(Xp^A+Yp^B+Zp^C )\equiv 0\pmod {p^D}.$$Could someone show me the details of the calculations please?

**Here is the part of the answer containing those parts:**

**The transformation**

Let $l=Lp^U$ and $j=Jp^V$ where $LJ \not\equiv 0\pmod p$. Then let $$A=a-b+s+V,B=t,C=2s+U,D=b.$$

*Theorem 2*

For non-negative integers $a\ge b,s$ and $t$, the equation
$$l (xp^s)^2 \equiv xp^{s}j p^{a-b} + yp^t\pmod{p^b}$$
can be solved with $xy \not\equiv 0\pmod p$ if and only if the equation
$$Xp^A+Yp^B+Zp^C \equiv 0\pmod {p^D}$$
can be solved with $XYZ \not\equiv 0\pmod p$.

*Proof*

If the $x,y$ equation can be solved then simply take $$X=xJ,Y=y,Z=-Lx^2.$$

Conversely, suppose we have a solution of the $X,Y,Z$ equation. Since $X$ and $L$ are coprime to $p$ we can solve
$$x \equiv -\frac {JZ}{LX}\pmod {p^D},y \equiv -\frac {J^2YZ}{LX^2}\pmod {p^D}.$$
Then $$  xp^{s}j p^{a-b} + yp^t-l(xp^s)^2=xJp^A+yp^B-Lx^2p^C$$
and this is
$$ -\frac {J^2Z}{LX^2}(Xp^A+Yp^B+Zp^C )\equiv 0\pmod {p^D}.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1.

$LX$ and $p^D$ are coprime. Therefore there are integers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $\alpha LX+\beta p^D=1$.

Then  $\alpha LX\equiv 1 \pmod {p^D}$  and so  $-\alpha JZ LX\equiv -JZ \pmod {p^D}$. Then take $x=-\alpha JZ$.

Similarly for the other congruence.

Q2.

Substitute $j=Jp^V$ and $l=Lp^U$ into $xp^{s}j p^{a-b} + yp^t-l(xp^s)^2$ and you will obtain $xJp^{s+a-b+V}+yp^t-x^2Lp^{s+2U}=xJp^A+yp^B-Lx^2p^C.$

Now substitute the expressions $x \equiv -\frac {JZ}{LX}\pmod {p^D},y \equiv -\frac {J^2YZ}{LX^2}\pmod {p^D}$ to obtain
$$-\frac {J^2Z}{LX^2}(Xp^A+Yp^B+Zp^C ),$$
where we know that $Xp^A+Yp^B+Zp^C\equiv 0 \pmod p^D$.

Comment: And here is my proof for the other equivalence:   $LX^2$ and $p^D$ are coprime. Therefore there are integers $\alpha' $ and $\beta '$ such that $\alpha' LX^2 + \beta^' p^D=1$. 

Then  $\alpha' LX^2 \equiv 1 \pmod {p^D}$  and so multiplying by $-J^2YZ$ we will get  $-\alpha' LX^2 J^2YZ\equiv -J^2YZ \pmod {p^D}$. Then take $y = -\alpha' J^2 YZ$. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that's exactly right.