# For what values of $l$ and $j$ (simultaneously) is the following congruence solvable?($a \leq b$)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, solution-verification

Here is the congruence I want to know for what values of $l$ and $j$ (simultaneously) is it solvable?

$$ p^{b-a}l (xp^s)^2 \equiv xp^{s}j  + yp^t\pmod{p^a} $$ where $x,y$ are not divisible by $p.$ and $s,a,t, b$ are any non-negative integers and $a \leq b.$

We have dealt here [For what values of $l$ and $j$ (simultaneously) is the following congruence solvable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3988796/for-what-values-of-l-and-j-simultaneously-is-the-following-congruence-solv) with a very similar case but with $a \geq b.$
**Now this is my trial for the solution:**

We will use the same theorem 1 used in the above mentioned question (together with its proof):

*Theorem 1*

Let $M=\min\{A,B,C,D\}$. Then the equation
$$Xp^A+Yp^B+Zp^C \equiv 0\pmod {p^D}$$

can be solved with $XYZ \not\equiv 0\pmod p$ if and only if either

$\bullet \hspace{1cm}M=D$

$\bullet \hspace{1cm}M$ is equal to precisely two of $\{A,B,C\}$

$\bullet \hspace{1cm}M$ is equal to all three of $\{A,B,C\}$ and $p\ne 2$.

*Proof*

CASE 1. If $M=D$

Then each of $Xp^A,Yp^B$ and $Zp^C$ is divisible by ${p^D}$ whatever the values of $X,Y$ or $Z$.

CASE 2. If $M=A=B,M<C$

The equation is solved by, for example, $Y=Z=1,X=-1-p^{C-M}$. By symmetry, we have similar solutions when $M=A=C$ and $M=B=C.$

CASE 3. If $M=A=B=C,M<D$

If $p\ne 2$ then the equation is solved by, for example, $Y=Z=1,X=p^{D-M}-2$. However, if $p=2$ then $X+Y+Z$ has to be even and so at least one of $X,Y,Z$ is even.

CASE 4. If $B,C$ and $D$ are all greater than $M=A$

Dividing the equation through by $p^M$ gives
$$X+Yp^{B-M}+Zp^{C-M} \equiv 0\pmod {p^{D-M}}$$ and then we have the contradiction that $p$ divides $X$.

By symmetry, we have similar contradictions when $M=B$ and $M=C.$

**The transformation**

Let $l=Lp^U$ and $j=Jp^V$ where $LJ \not\equiv 0\pmod p$. Then **(Note here is a difference between the 2 questions)**let $$A = s+V, B=t,C=2s + b -a + U ,D = a.$$

*Theorem 2*

For non-negative integers $a,b,s$ and $t$ with $a \leq b$, the equation
$$p^{b-a} l (xp^s)^2 \equiv xp^{s}j  + yp^t\pmod{p^a}$$
can be solved with $xy \not\equiv 0\pmod p$ if and only if the equation
$$Xp^A+Yp^B+Zp^C \equiv 0\pmod {p^D}$$
can be solved with $XYZ \not\equiv 0\pmod p$.

*Proof*

If the $x,y$ equation can be solved then simply take $$X=xJ,Y=y,Z=-Lx^2.$$

Conversely, suppose we have a solution of the $X,Y,Z$ equation. Since $X$ and $L$ are coprime to $p$ we can get the following congruence equations:

$$x \equiv -\frac {JZ}{LX}\pmod {p^D},y \equiv -\frac {J^2YZ}{LX^2}\pmod {p^D}.$$

**Details of their calculations:**

**Details of solution for $x \equiv -\frac {JZ}{LX}\pmod {p^D}$**

$LX$ and $p^D$ are coprime. Therefore there are integers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $\alpha LX+\beta p^D=1$.\

Then  $\alpha LX\equiv 1 \pmod {p^D}$  and so  $-\alpha JZ LX\equiv -JZ \pmod {p^D}$. Then take $x=-\alpha JZ$.\

**Details of solution for $y \equiv -\frac {J^2YZ}{LX^2}\pmod {p^D}$.**

$LX^2$ and $p^D$ are coprime. Therefore there are integers $\alpha' $ and $\beta '$ such that $\alpha' LX^2 + \beta' p^D=1$.\

Then  $\alpha' LX^2 \equiv 1 \pmod {p^D}$  and so multiplying by $-J^2YZ$ we will get  $-\alpha'LX^2 J^2YZ\equiv -J^2YZ \pmod {p^D}$. Then take $y = -\alpha' J^2 YZ$.

Then $$  xp^{s}j + yp^t - p^{b-a}l(xp^s)^2=xJp^A+yp^B-Lx^2p^C$$

and by substituting the previous congruences of $x$ and $y,$ we get

$$ -\frac {J^2Z}{LX^2}(Xp^A+Yp^B+Zp^C )\equiv 0\pmod {p^D}.$$ Because we know that $ Xp^A+Yp^B+Zp^C \equiv 0\pmod {p^D}.$

**Conclusion**

We can now see that the original equation can be solved if and only if the quantities $$A = s + V,B=t,C= 2s + b -a + U, D = a$$ satisfy the conditions of Theorem 1. Let $v_p(n)$ represent the highest power of $p$ which divides the number $n$. You will notice that the precise values of $j$ and $l$ do not affect the existence of solutions; all that matters is $v_p(j)$ and $v_p(l)$ .

CASE 1. $t\ge a$,  $v_p(l)\ge 2a - 2s -b$ and  $v_p(j)\ge a-s$.

Where the first inequality because $B \geq D,$ the second inequality because $C \geq D$ and the third inequality because $A \geq D.$

CASE 2. There are three possibilities.

$v_p(l)> t-2s -b +a$ and  $v_p(j)= t-s$.

Where the inequality because $B < C$ and the equality because $A = B.$

$v_p(j)< t - s$ and  $v_p(l) = -b +a -s + v_p(j)$.

Where the inequality because $A \leq B$ and the equality because $A = C.$

$v_p(l)= t-2s - b + a$ and  $v_p(j) > t-s$.

Where the equality because $B = C$ and the inequality because $B < A.$

CASE 3. If $p\ne 2$, then $t< a$,  $v_p(j)= t-s$ and  $v_p(l)= a - b + t - 2s$.

Where the inequality because $B < D,$ the first equality because $B = A$ and the second equality because $B = C.$

**Is this a correct solution or I need to adjust anything?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well done. All the calculations are correct.

In the statement of the problem it might be best to say $a$ is positive so as not to have an equation modulo $1$.

Also, there is a special possibility in CASE 3 if $p=2$. (Unless this case is of interest to you it might be simpler to say $p$ is odd from the outset.)

In the case that $p=2$ then, for a solution, we require at least one of $X=xJ,Y=y,Z=-Lx^2$ to be even. However, these quantities cannot be multiples of $p$ and so are all odd. So there is no solution for CASE 3 when $p=2$.

Comment: Could you please explain to me the special passibility in CASE 3 if $p = 2,$ what will happen?

Comment: Also, I did not understand what do you mean by this statement "so as not to have an equation modulo 1"? from where the modulo 1 will come?

Comment: If you allow a=0, then the equation will be modulo $p^0=1$. I'll be happy to do the p=2 case tomorrow.

Comment: By the way thanks my skillful teacher :)

Comment: Ok that is fine.

Comment: You're certainly good at this topic now :)

Comment: I've now expanded on the p=2 case in the answer.